# Word for the next generation that you treat like your siblings

Tags: word-choice

In academia, it is your responsibility to guide the students to get familiar with the academic environment, such as advising them to write their dissertations. Although it is a responsibility, because these students are in the situation exactly what you used to be, and in the spirit of paying forward, you want to share with them your most experience with enthusiastic. In my language, these students are named as a kind of sibling. Is there any word that is equivalent to this?

I have thought about *junior*, but I'm afraid that the readers will mistake it with third year student. And I think that *inferior* is not a positive word.

Comment: In English (and European culture), the professor doctoral student relationship is complicated. Sometimes it is talked about like a marriage, sometimes like a colleague, sometimes like an master/apprentice, and sometimes like the traditional teacher/student. So one word probably won't fit, and though described as the previous situations, aren't central (e.g. no one would refer to a student in spousal terms). You're right, 'inferior' is not positive and is not used. 'Sibling' is like colleague but much too equal (and no one considers the professor/doctoral student anywhere near equal to use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be looking for a term like [*protégé(e)*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/prot%C3%A9g%C3%A9) ("A person who is guided and supported by an older and more experienced or influential person") or [*mentee*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mentee) ("A person who is advised, trained, or counseled by a mentor").

(Links to definitions at Oxforddictionaries.com.)

Comment: I'm familiar with *mentee*, but is *protege* familiar with most of people, at least in academians? I'm afraid that using the latter one will makes people think that I'm pedantic.

Comment: @Ooker - I think most academics would be fully familiar with the term.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any differences between them?

Comment: Not much, besides the fact that 'protégé' can also refer to a person outside a formal academic or workplace-based relationship that may include a financial component. For instance, a wealthy patron might adopt a struggling artist or composer as their protégé (giving them financial assistance), but you could not call the artist or composer in question a *mentee*; the latter term implies receiving a degree of training, guidance, supervision or career help.

Comment: I would like to ask one more question: do these two words have the familiar feeling to the mentor?

Comment: @Ooker - I would imagine so. Neither word is particularly specialized or rare in use.

Comment: Actually what I mean is the intimate meaning in the *familiar* word. I know that both of them are widely used.

Comment: @Ooker - I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by "the intimate meaning in the *familiar* word". What is an 'intimate meaning'?

Comment: I'm sorry for not making it clear. I mean that the relationship between the mentor and mentee is not only workship (I make this word), but also friendship. I want to know if these two words reflect this relationship.

Comment: @Ooker - 'Mentor'/'mentee' carries no particular connotation of friendship. Meanwhile, a protégé may or may not also be friends with their sponsor/patron.

Comment: 'protégé' is a very particular kind of realtionship (definitely not like a sibling) and only very particular mentor/mentee relationships are like this. A 'protégé' is a very special junior, one who shines and could be a replacement for, or match the genius of the senior.